# Partially off/loading slices of a tensor to/from disk with jax

Tags: lazy-loading, tensor, jax

I'm working with really big tensors, but I only use small rectangular regions at a time. I don't want to split the tensor apart since my window is constantly sliding foreward. I'd like to offload the parts of the tensor that are not in my window to the disk, since there's no way it's going to fit in memory. Is there a simple way to do this?

---

##### Bigger Picture

My code looks like this:

```py
def act(self, obs):
  t = obs.t
  self.vision[FRAME_RATE*t: FRAME_RATE*(t+INTERVAL)] = obs.video
  self.hearing[AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE*t: AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE*(t+INTERVAL)] = obs.sound
  self.action[t] = self.model(self.vision[-VIDEO_WINDOW:], self.hearing[-AUDIO_WINDOW:])
  return self.action[t]
```

which requires working with really long tensors, and it seems simpler to just write or find a library that offloads to the disk behind the scenes instead of chunking it myself.

---

I found the `lazytensors` library, but I'm looking for a jax solution
I considered manually slicing my tensor, but that's just so wasteful to allocate, copy, release for every window move

---

:thanks: Thanks for any help you're able to provide!